# How can use a pipeline in Scrapy when using a spider through the parse command

Tags: python, scrapy

```
scrapy parse --spider=$spider -c parse_thread -d 100 --nolog $url
```

Is there a way to enable pipelines for items processed using the parse command?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `parse` command instead of `crawl`?

Comment: I want to just crawl through a small set of specific urls, but you gave me an idea. I think I will just set the urls I want in the start_urls list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`crawl`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#crawl) command it will use the pipelines specified in your settings and you can add urls to the [`start_urls`](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_urls) attribute or, if you want to get these urls to callback a specific function, you can override [`start_requests`](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) and issue your requests there manually for your urls:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(url1, callback=self.my_callback)
    yield Request(url2, callback=self.my_callback)
```